# I can't find a concept of a delete in the Spring Resource abstractions, is there any?

Tags: spring, abstraction

The Spring Resource abstraction (org.springframework.core.io.Resource) is, to me, a concept to address a resource, with the abilities to find a resource by name, to test if it exists, to read the contents of a resource, optionally to write the contents of a resource. FileSystemResource is one concrete implementation, many others exist.

When trying to understand an abstraction, I often look for some completeness/closure of the set of operations. Sure, that's not the primary focus of the Resource interface, but nevertheless: Resource, by itself, with its exists() and lastModified() methods, suggests that the contents it addresses has some lifecycle. Through WritableResource, implementors with write ability can modify a resource, again interacting with its lifecycle, in FileSystemResource and others, actually creating the resource.

For completeness, what can be created should be able to be deleted. Resource does not have an abstraction of a delete, and I could not find any in its children. Looking into abstractions of a container for resources, which might be responsible for a resource's lifecycle, I found ResourceLoader and it's children, again with no delete ability.

Resource getFile() opens a way to get to an object with delete ability, but on that way we lose abstraction.

If you were dealing with similar resonings, what was your approach?

Comment: this question would better be suited to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: yes, I thought of that too, but I felt it was better here because it closely relates to Spring, am I wrong?